# Thunderbird: STARTTLS / Password method

Tags: thunderbird, ssl

In Thunderbird, for my e-mail account setup, I see

Server Settings:

Connection Security: STARTTLS
Authentication method: Normal password

Other choices for Authentication are:
 - Encrypted
 - Kerberos
 - NTLM

What are the advantages of using Encrypted? (I thought STARTTLS was good enough)?

What do I need to do to enable encrypted passwords on my machine (RHEL, Sendmail)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STARTTLS will still transfer your password encrypted over the wire. The 'encrypted password' settings will encrypt the actual password.

Personally I like STARTTLS because all the data transferred is encrypted, not just the passwords. Handy if I'm dealing with emails containing things I don't want random network lurkers to see.

Comment: Ah OK... so with STARTTLS, encrypted password option doesn't mean much... it already handles that.  Makes sense...